# Keyword arguments for java? What do you think?

Tags: java, arguments, keyword

This really isn't so much an answerable question as a 'What do you think' question.

In python, the programmer has the option to use keywords arguments in their function calls. For example

```
def doSomething(test=True, numBacon=5, ...):
```

Does any one other than me think that would be a fantasic idea for java? I know that varargs can do a lot, but it doesn't come close to being as useful are keyword arguments. So I ask the world, what do you think?

Comment: I think it's a good addition to most languages (the exception being certain functional languages which are restricted to boring fixed-length parameter list and dead-simple parameter passing but get awesome implicit currying in return). But then again, I'm a Python guy.

Comment: Note that a common tendency is to provide information about "this is a test" as annotations (meta-information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might - if you could pass a map into a method, which would look up the map's keyed entries. It would require an inline, typeless map declaration, which wouldn't be very useful outside of this kind of limited scope - and since it'd be very limited, I'd end up saying "No, not required." If you want the facility, use Python. If you want the capability in a JVM, use Jython or JRuby.

Comment: A bit of a narrow perspective, look at how it was implemented in C#.